# Can't find html element with jquery id selector when using variable as parameter to the jquery function to find it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Jquery can't find html element via ID selector when the ID is provided via a variable. 
When I provide the id directly then it can find the corresponding html element. (See example)

replicated it in the debug console of google Chrome. You can see the results in the screenshot. 
Also debugged it with google chrome. The variable is holding the right content and is not undefined, when its handed over to the jquery(var) function.

```
var test = "#test\\\\.debug\\\\.component3 tr"
// inside test is now: "#test\\.debug\\.component3 tr"
$(test) // won't give me the expected result
//
$("#test\\.debug\\.component3 tr") // gives the expected result!
```

See the example screenshot:

[image]

Comment: seems unlikely that is different. I am betting test is `var test = "#test\\\\.debug\\\\.component3 tr"` because run `var test2 = "#test\\.debug\\.component3 tr"; console.log(test2);` in the console, the console will output one slash, not 2.

Comment: Yes you're right. In the variable assignment within my code I assigned it like you said (var test = "#test\\\\.debug\\\\.component3 tr"). I did it like that, because the API documentation of jquery statet, that you have to have two backslashes in front of the "." character. (And to have two backslashes in the resulting variable you have to assign an extra backslash each for every real backslash as an 
escape within js.

Comment: Actually by inserting just two instead of four it started to work now. I just don't get why.. because for me it looks similar:  `var test = "test\\\\.\debug\\\\.component3 tr"; //resulting in: test = "test\\.debug\\.component3 tr" //which doesnt work within $(test) and $("test\\.\debug\\.component3 tr") // works directly`

Comment: Edited to include image in the question

Comment: Basic escaping of characters

Comment: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes